# Disable Spring TestExecutionListeners from inherited class

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-test

I have the following scenario:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(BasicListener.class)
public @interface AnnotationOne {
}

@AnnotationOne
public class TestClassOne extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
...
}
```

And since:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ServletTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
}
```

For some reason, the TestExecutionListeners don't get merged. So, is there a way to disable the TestExecutionListeners defined by the parent class?

My main concern is to have the BasicListener working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are experiencing is due to a *bug* in core Spring: an inherited annotation will shadow a locally declared composed annotation.

In your use case, `@TestExecutionListeners` is the *inherited* annotation, and `@AnnotationOne` is the locally declared *composed annotation*.

This bug has been fixed in Spring Framework 4.2 RC1. For details, see [SPR-12749](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12749).

If you'd like a work-around before 4.2 is released, the following should work for you, but you will not be able to use your custom `@AnnotationOne` annotation if your class extends from `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests`:

```java
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = BasicListener.class, inheritListeners = false)
public class TestClassOne extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    // ...
}
```

Generally speaking, `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` adds very little value. So you're probably better off with the following approach:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(BasicListener.class)
public class TestClassOne {
    // ...
}
```

Or even:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@AnnotationOne
public class TestClassOne {
    // ...
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)